# Geometric interpretation of parallelogram law determines the inner product

Tags: real-analysis

We know that if we have parallelogram law,we can determine an inner product, I want to know what is geometric interpretation behind it since the inner product gives an geometric structure of the vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner product is a measure of "how parallel" two vectors are. If you normalize your vectors then the inner product is a number between [-1, 1] and the value of "how parallel" the vectors are can be taken to be the cosine of the angle between the vectors so that a value of 1 means they are parallel in the same direction, -1 means parallel in opposite directions, 0 means they are orthogonal, etc. In fact, in any inner product space you can define the "angle" between two vectors by taking the inner product of normalized vectors to be the cosine of the angle. That gives a natural geometric structure (by defining angles) in your inner product space.